# How do I set up a proxy object in the main application NIB?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, interface-builder

I would like to set up a proxy object in the application NIB file. The problem is that the NIB file is the main application NIB that gets loaded automatically by the application and therefore I cannot set up the `UINibProxiedObjectsKey` dictionary as described in the documentation. Is there a way to set up a proxy object in the main application NIB? Or can I tap into the code that loads the main application NIB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My main problem was that I was trying to use Interface Builder as a dependency injection tool for the whole application. I had an instance of an object that had to be created in code and then I needed to pass this instance to other objects in the NIB, therefore the need for proxy objects. In the end I found the proxy object stuff to be overkill. I created a separate class that takes care of wiring my objects together and the problem disappeared.