# External Object placeholders in Xcode's Interface Builder are missing

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, xcode5

If I remember correctly, it use to be possible to add external object placeholders to a NIB in interface builder. This was used to add reference to existing instances of objects that the NIB doesn't create but need to be referenced by other objects in Interface Builder. Similar to "File's owner" and Application objects.

I also found some mention in older SO questions of this technique, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950674/how-to-use-a-common-target-object-to-handle-actions-outlets-of-multiple-views)

I am using Xcode 5.0.1 on Mavericks and there is no trace of these "External Objects" in interface builder. It seems that it is not possible to add anything to the placeholders anymore. I went through [Xcode's release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/) since Xcode 4.0 and there is no mention of this being removed (although there are few mentions of dragging placeholder, whatever that means).

So, any idea if this was intentionally removed? A bug? Is there any workaround or replacement for this feature?

Answer (score -3):

Open the project which has already used external object, you will find 'external object' in the interface builder. So I guess the external object may be deprecated and not appear by default.

For an alternative way, you can use 'object' instead.

Comment: You can't use "Object" instead. Those are not the same things. A placeholder is just a way to connect to existing instance so you can access it from Interface Builder. When you add an "Object", an instance of that class will be created when the NIB is loaded. I need to connect to a singleton from Interface Builder, so an "Object" won't work.

Comment: @danielv The external object has been re-added at xcode 5.1, just a remainder if you have not notice this. (creating a .xib, and search 'object' you will see it)

Comment: @danielv Do you use storyboard? If so create a .xib file, you will find it. You can not use external object as the storyboard is initialized by iOS, and you can not pass any external object.

Comment: No storyboard. I created a new (Mac) project and searched it with the newly created xib open.

Comment: I do the experiment on the iOS project.

Comment: Ok, I see it if I create an iOS project but not for OSX project

Comment: Yes... Looking up the sdk, for NSNib, - (BOOL)instantiateWithOwner:(id)owner topLevelObjects:(NSArray **)topLevelObjects, for UINib, – instantiateWithOwner:options: (pass the external object from options). I think mac project just does not support the external object.

Comment: I see. Well, Will have to continue living without then. Thanks for the info.