# Change/Modify Runtime User defined attribute before Instantiating ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

In short, I want to know "How to change Runtime User defined attributes before instantiating a View Controller" 
**Why I Need this**
I am creating an application which uses multiple storyboards. I have a main storyboard with a UIViewController designated as LinkViewController. It has a string attribute, which tells it which storyboard has to be linked. now what I want to do is, I want to change that attribute at appDelegate & then instantiate the viewController. So far not able to do it.

This is what I am doing:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];         
EffLinkHomeVC *rootController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"linkView"];
 rootController.storyBoardName = @"wxyzForiPhone";
 self.window.rootViewController = rootController;
```

I have found several other ways to work around. But I just want to know more clearly about altering "Runtime User defined attributes". Thank you all.  :)

Comment: Means you want to change the rootViewController of your app?

Comment: no… i'am just starting the app with custom View controller

Comment: Is storyBoardName a custom NSString* attribute on your EffLinkHomeVC or something?

Comment: Ya.. custom NSString* only.

Comment: and what would it do with that attribute that it cannot do after instantiation?

Comment: Loading views from storyboard @Mihai

Comment: You could do that in viewDidLoad or even viewWillAppear and it should be in time. Sorry if I'm missing something, i just don't the problem. PS: wouldn't it be easier to just create Eff... programatically as it seems to not have a view needing storyboard?

Comment: Ya I Know that & I have found a way to workaround also. I placed bounty on this question to know "How to change Runtime User defined attributes before instantiating a View Controller". @MihaiTimar

Comment: I'd love to know the reason of down vote, if somebody could tell me.. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can only do this with proxy/external objects available in nibs.
Check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950674/how-to-use-a-common-target-object-to-handle-actions-outlets-of-multiple-views/6952422#6952422) to see a nice example of their usage.

By the looks of it this functionality is hidden or removed from storyboards. The only documented ways of configuring are static. In your case it would be statically configured with the properties from the storyboard you are using. If this suffices, you could use the key value mechanism to statically configure a different value for each storyboard.

Other than that you only have the normal post init viewController methods.

Comment: It's not exactly what i was asking for, but 1 up for new concept.